# ATI Raedon 68e1 Binary drivers not working in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx, binary

I was using the amdcccle to set the graphical settings provided by the ATI graphics card, both fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle was installed by default. Then I followed the ubuntu community i.e

```
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI
```

[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

and tried to install the BinaryDriver , but after installing this binary driver I couldnot open the amdcccle window, it gives error and says proper driver was not installed for the graphics card.

Then I uninstalled this binary driver and again tried to install the fglrx and fglrx-amdccle from the ubuntu repositories. But even after installation I couldnot run

```
aticonfig --initial

It gives command not found -- aticonfig
```

And

```
fglrxinfo

It gives command not found - fglrxinfo
```

According to the link it should work but I am stuck because of this error and my graphics card is not working.

I am out of options and searching for ATI hd 68e1 driver and even cant get the exactly named driver. Please help me out of this.

Comment: At last solved this with update-alternatives command. Its a life saver command :) , Got help from this helpful link    http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Lucid_Installation_Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last solved this with

```
sudo update-alternatives --set gl_conf /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf
```

command to set **gl_conf** to **fglrx** as an altenative to **mesa**. Its a life saver command :) , Got help from this helpful 
 [link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Lucid_Installation_Guide)